# Clipping polygon using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, clip

I want to clip a polygon using Qgis "clip" tool. The problem is that the resulting polygon presents areas that where not clipped off. 
The first screenshot shows the layer I want to clip using the polygon on the second screenshot. In the resulting layer (3rd screenshot) you can see the areas of the clipping layer that were not clipped.

How can this be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide test data? Which version of QGIS are you using? Are you using Clip from the Vector menu?

Comment: I'm using QGIS  Pisa and yes, i'm using that clip tool.
I could provide both vectors, would you want me to send them to you?

Comment: Please put the files on a server and post links here.

Comment: You could try clipping again your strange resulting layer with the same clip layer.

Comment: "Vector BC" is the layer that I would like to clip using "Too" as the cutter
CRS: EPSG:32611 (WGS84/UTM zone 11N).
thanks
[URL=http://wikisend.com/download/208610/documents-export-2015-09-28.zip]documents-export-2015-09-28.zip[/URL]

Comment: "Vector BC" has several categories under the column "TIPOS", that is the info I will like to get on clipped shape

Comment: At first I thought it might be because some of the shapes only touch at corners, but upon close examination I can't find a pattern in what isn't being clipped though it does appear to be making new shapes out of the holes. I ran a geometry check in ArcGIS on both shapefiles and found no errors. I note that both are already in the same projection. I could not replicate the issue using ArcGIS's Clip tool - everything seems to have been clipped correctly. I don't have QGIS loaded at the moment to test there, so I'm afraid I can't offer much help.

Comment: @ChrisW, thanks for doing that! I hope there is a solution...

Comment: There were almost 200 invalid geometry errors reported from the Topology plugin in QGIS 2.10.1. I repaired the shapefile using "MakeValid" in the Processing toolbox (provided by the LWGEOM Plugin, which required lwgeom.dll - at least on Windows). Clip then worked without producing filled holes. But I used the "Clip vectors by polygon" tool in the Processing toolbox because the Vector menu clip tool got stuck at 2% for about 2 hours.

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon. The clip tool I used produced some of the same filled holes but in different spots...

Comment: @SaultDon, thanks for the info! I will repair the shapefiles...
hope this problem has a solution!